# Create a function that produces a list of multiples ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a function:

```
let rec multiply x ls =
match ls with 
[] -> []
| h::tl -> (x * h) :: multiply x tl
```

multiply 2 [1;2;3] = [2;4;6]

I would like a function that calls multiply from n to 0. I keep having problems because of the base case:

```
let rec multiply_all x ls = if x > 0 
then (multiply n ls) :: multiply_all (n-1) (ls) else ????
```

I am not sure what to put after the else. I tried to make it

```
if x > 1 then (multiply n ls) :: multiply_all (n-1) (ls) else multiply all 1.
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an other solution :

```
let multiply_all n l =
  let multiply n= List.map (( * ) n) in
  let rec aux i acc =
    if i > n then acc
    else aux (i+1) (multiply i l :: acc)
  in
  aux 1 [] 
;;
```

Test :

```
# multiply_all 5 [1;2;3];;
- : int list list =
[[5; 10; 15]; [4; 8; 12]; [3; 6; 9]; [2; 4; 6]; [1; 2; 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting `1` there certainly doesn't work since `multiply_all` must return a list. So you need a list (of lists of `int`) to put there. But which list should it be?

The short answer is that in such simple cases, the list you need is usually the empty list: `[]`.

As a slightly longer answer, we can consider the case for `multiply_all 0` in relation to the intended results of `multiply_all 1`, `multiply_all 2`, etc., and try to find a pattern that fits. We want `multiply_all` to behave like this:

```
# multiply_all 2 [1;2;3];;
- : int list list = [[2; 4; 6]; [1; 2; 3]]
# multiply_all 1 [1;2;3];;
- : int list list = [[1; 2; 3]]
```

So calling `multiply_all` with some number *N* as first argument should give us a list of length *N*. In particular, `multiply_all` with *N* = 0 should give a list of length 0. The list of length 0 is the empty list.

Here is your completed definition:

```
let rec multiply_all x ls =
  if x > 0 then (multiply x ls) :: multiply_all (x-1) (ls) else []
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your `multiply` method is pretty inefficient since it isn't *tail recursive*. Furthermore, the standard library provides you with tools to make that kind of function easier to write:

```
let multiply n = List.map (( * ) n);;;
val multiply : int -> int list -> int list = <fun>

multiply 5 [1;2;3];;
- : int list = [5; 10; 15]
```

*Note*: Also, use partial application when it doesn't obfuscate your code.

As of `multiply_all`, I'm not sure how to achieve it without JaneStreet's `Core` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110714/cores-list-init-in-pervasives)). However, here is a possible implementation using `Core`:

```
open Core.Std;; (*Using Core*)
let multiply_all n l =
  let multiples = List.init n ~f:(fun x -> n-x) in (*This doesn't exist in Pervasives*)
  List.map multiples ~f:(fun m -> multiply l m);;
val multiply_all : int list -> int -> int list list = <fun>

multiply_all 5 [1;2;3];;
- : int list list = [[5; 10; 15]; [4; 8; 12]; [3; 6; 9]; [2; 4; 6]; [1; 2; 3]]
```

Hope it helps. I'll keep this answer updated with my findings about `List.init`.