# Core's `List.init` in Pervasives?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

I'm used to JaneStreet's `Core` library. Its `List` module has a neat `init` function:

```
List.init;;
- : int -> f:(int -> 'a) -> 'a list = <fun>
```

It allows you to create a list with using a custom function to initialize elements:

```
List.init 5 ~f:(Fn.id);;
- : int list = [0; 1; 2; 3; 4]

List.init 5 ~f:(Int.to_string);;
- : string list = ["0"; "1"; "2"; "3"; "4"]
```

However, this function doesn't seem to exist in `Pervasives`, which is sad. Am I missing something, or do I have to implement it myself? And if I do need to write it, how do I achieve this?

**EDIT**:

I have written an imperative version of `init`, but it doesn't feel right to have to resort to OCaml's imperative features in such a case. :(

```
let init n ~f =
  let i = ref 0 in
  let l = ref [] in
  while !i < n do
    l := (f !i) :: !l;
    incr i;
  done;
  List.rev !l
;;
```

**EDIT 2:**

I've opened a [pull request](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/1034) on OCaml's GitHub to have this feature included.

**EDIT 3:**

The feature was released in OCaml 4.06.

Comment: as a general comment: don't expect any kind of convenience from Pervasives. if you want a full standard lib, you'll have to use either Core or Containers or Batteries (there may be others) currently.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive implementation is fairly straightforward. However, it is not tail-recursive, which means that you'll risk a stack overflow for large lists:

```
let init_list n ~f =
  let rec init_list' i n f =
    if i >= n then []
    else (f i) :: (init_list' (i+1) n f)
  in init_list' 0 n f
```

We can transform it into a tail-recursive version using the usual techniques:

```
let init_list n ~f =
  let rec init_list' acc i n f =
    if i >= n then acc
    else init_list' ((f i) :: acc) (i+1) n f
  in List.rev (init_list' [] 0 n f)
```

This uses an accumulator and also needs to reverse the intermediate result, as the list is constructed in reverse. Note that we could also use `f (n-i-1)` instead of `f i` to avoid reversing the list, but this may lead to unexpected behavior if `f` has side-effects.

An alternative and shorter solution is to simply use `Array.init` as a starting point:

```
let init_list n ~f = Array.(init n f |> to_list)
```

Comment: `Array.init` is a thing but not `List.init`? This is a shame. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the code from JaneStreet and **use it**.

The code look's like (but not exactly the same) :

```
let init n ~f =
  if n < 0 then raise (Invalid_argument "init");
  let rec loop i accum =
    if i = 0 then accum
    else loop (i-1) (f (i-1) :: accum)
  in
  loop n []
;;
```

You can find the original code inside core_list0.ml from the package core_kernel.